# Why can't the kernel run init?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, qemu, init

I've downloaded the Raspbian image on [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). I'm trying to compile a kernel that can be used to boot the image within qemu.

I downloaded the Linux kernel source from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org) and ran:

```
make versatile_defconfig
make menuconfig
```

I then added the following features to the kernel:

- PCI support (CONFIG_PCI)
- SCSI Device Support (CONFIG_SCSI)
- SCSI Disk Support (CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD)
- SYM53C8XX Version 2 SCSI Support (CONFIG_SCSI_SYM53C8XX_2)
- The Extended 3 (ext3) filesystem (CONFIG_EXT3_FS)
- The Extended 4 (ext4) filesystem (CONFIG_EXT4_FS)

I also loop mounted the disk image and:

- commented out `/etc/ld.so.preload`
- adjusted `/etc/fstab` to use `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`

I then unmounted the image and attempted to start the machine with:

```
qemu-system-arm \
    -M versatilepb \
    -m 256 \
    -kernel linux-4.3/arch/arm/boot/zImage \
    -hda 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.img \
    -serial stdio \
    -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw console=ttyAMA0"
```

The kernel was able to mount the filesystem but it immediately ran into some trouble:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004

CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.3.0 #1
Hardware name: ARM-Versatile PB
[<c001b5c0>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0017e18>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<c0017e18>] (show_stack) from [<c0069860>] (panic+0x84/0x1ec)
[<c0069860>] (panic) from [<c0025b98>] (do_exit+0x81c/0x850)
[<c0025b98>] (do_exit) from [<c0025c5c>] (do_group_exit+0x3c/0xb8)
[<c0025c5c>] (do_group_exit) from [<c002dfcc>] (get_signal+0x14c/0x59c)
[<c002dfcc>] (get_signal) from [<c001bf28>] (do_signal+0x84/0x3a0)
[<c001bf28>] (do_signal) from [<c0017a94>] (do_work_pending+0xb8/0xc8)
[<c0017a94>] (do_work_pending) from [<c0014f30>] (slow_work_pending+0xc/0x20)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004
```

At first, I wondered if this wasn't related to SELinux. I tried booting the kernel with:

```
selinux=0 enforcing=0
```

...but it made absolutely no difference.

What am I doing wrong? And what does this error mean?

#### Updates

I have also tried the following, with no luck:

- I tried compiling with and without `CONFIG_VFP` enabled
- I added `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS` and `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT`
- Applying [this patch](https://github.com/johnlane/rpi-utils/blob/master/kernel/linux-arm.patch) and enabling `CPU_V6`, `CONFIG_MMC_BCM2835`, & `CONFIG_MMC_BCM2835_DMA`
- Using the [`gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian` toolchain](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian)
- Compiling a simple C program with the toolchain and then passing its path to the kernel via `init=` works - leading me to believe there's a discrepancy between binary formats

  - `file <sample program>`:

    ```
    ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=e5ec8884499c51b248df60aedddfc9acf72cdbd4, not stripped
    ```
  - `file <file from the image>`:

    ```
    ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=3e92423821f3325f8cb0ec5d918a7a1c76bbd72c, stripped`
    ```
  - [diff of ELF header](https://www.diffchecker.com/pu4mvze8)

I compiled [this simple C program](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13320993/) with the toolchain:

```
<path>/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --static simple.c -o simple
```

...and copied it to `/root` in the image, changing the `init=` boot parameter to `/root/simple`. This gives me the following when booting:

```
Starting bash...
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004
```

It seems to be choking on the `execv()` call.

Comment: I would say this is an issue regarding hard floating point support. Do you have CONFIG_VFP=y?

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni `cat .config | grep CONFIG_VFP` yields `CONFIG_VFP=y` - seems like it is enabled.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni I've tried the kernel with and without `CONFIG_VFP` and it makes no difference.

Comment: I think Alexandre is on the right track, but VFP isn't the problematic setting. `versatilepb` is an ARM926 CPU, which is older than the RPi's ARM1176, so Raspbian binaries may be using some other feature that isn't being emulated. From http://www.unixmen.com/emulating-raspbian-using-qemu/, does `-cpu arm1176` help?

Comment: @Gilles as a parameter to qemu? No, it doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe try an armel toolchain? (For the actual program that keeps running, not just for the relay stub. You could use busybox — grab the busybox-static binary from debian armel.)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a somewhat aged question, but since there are *still* no good answers for testing Raspberry Pi images with QEMU, allow me to contribute a partial answer.

I wanted to use the [Ubuntu 16.04 raspi3 image](https://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/) with QEMU. Downloaded it, extracted it, mounted the boot partition, got the vmlinuz file and the initrd file, and ... qemu-system-arm -M blabla -cpu ... -kernel ...  doesn't work. Black screen.

Then using a kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie from [here](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel) with the xenial image/rootfs led to the same "init killed" problem you have.

But since I'm using a known good kernel, and since your simple statically linked C program works, it's likely the problem only surfaces when one uses the dynamic linker. (And the linker is not particularly sensitive to kernels, because the ld-2.24 from the latest debian9 (stretch) based raspbian works fine on a 4.4 debian8 (jessie) based kernel.)

Even after copying the files that do work on/with the "jessie" image into the ubuntu xenial image I only got a weird "calling preinit: KE" error.

Oh, and anyone looking at compiling a kernel for a Raspberry Pi, should check [this](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation) site, which directly references the "[official](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md)" docs/howto.

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried booting ARM images with QEMU with no reliable success. I am sorry to say that you will have to use real hardware to work with a ARM OS, or wait patiently for developers to make a more reliable emulator for ARM.

Its Dec 2018, and still there are still issues with `qemu-system-arm`.

I was able to boot Raspbian Jessie on a QEMU emulator using a freshly installed Ubuntu 18 Bionic, however it was not stable for my work so I had to leave it for real hardware. It would freeze up frequently.

`qemu-system-arm` did not work on my OS, so I used Virtualbox to install Ubuntu Bionic and inside Bionic I installed Raspbian with QEMU.

I followed this tutorial: https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the right cross-compiler?

In my case, I followed the link below and I was getting the same error with exit code 0x00000004, when I used **arm-linux-gnueabihf-** (i.e., hard-float) gcc compiler.

https://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/Build-the-Linux-kernel-and-Busybox-and-run-on-QEMU

When I recompiled everything with **arm-linux-gnueabi-**, the kernel booted successfully. Please check if this resolves your problem.

Comment: The OP mentions a *very* similar situation: "Using the gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian toolchain ... <path>/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --static simple.c -o simple" -- is your answer distinct from that?

Comment: Recompiled with arm-linux-gnueabi - no changes

Answer (score -2):

The linux kernel does not run init anymore. Instead, it runs systemd which is like init but a bit more advanced features and extra multitasking capabilities, although against unix philosophy systemd is so useful.

Comment: not sure if this is know to the be how

Comment: This is not correct. Many embedded Linux systems run the latest kernel without the use of Systemd, oftentimes using a slimmer init system, such as the one provided by BusyBox.

Comment: Counter example: [Devuan Linux](https://www.devuan.org/).